# Installing GeoIP on Amazon EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, geoip

I am trying to install GeoIP module to block country specific traffic to my website. My Website is LAMP configured and hosted on Amazon AWS EC2 instance.

As per some article on google, I followed these steps:

```
yum install epel-release
```

In response, I get

> **Package epel-release-6-8.9.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version**
>
> **Nothing to do**

I followed Next Step,

```
sudo yum --enablerepo epel install mod_geoip GeoIP GeoIP-devel GeoIP-data zlib-devel
```

And received conflicts error,

> **Error: GeoIP-GeoLite-data conflicts with GeoIP-1.4.8-1.5.amzn1.x86_64**
>
> **Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64**
>
> **Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64**

How to resolve these conflicts or bypass these conflicts to install GeoIP module on EC2?

Comment: EPEL is not compatible with Amazon Linux. Use a different Linux distribution.

Answer (score 3):

As @MichaelHampton says EPEL is not compatible with Amazon Linux.

However you can often rebuild the EPEL **source RPM**s for Amazon Linux.

1. Download the required packages' `*.src.rpm` files from EPEL, e.g. `mod_geoip-...src.rpm`.
2. Run `rpmbuild --rebuild mod_geoip-...src.rpm`
3. If everything works you will get `mod_geoip-...x86-64.rpm` built for your OS.

However chances are that a direct rebuild won't work - it may have missing dependencies, etc. In that case you will have to dig down to the RPM spec files and try to fix it. It may not be trivial, but you will certainly learn a lot about how RPMs are built along the way :)

Comment: cat: /usr/include/httpd/.mmn: No such file or directory
error: Failed build dependencies:
 httpd-devel is needed by mod_geoip-1.2.10-1.amzn1.x86_64
 GeoIP-devel >= 1.4.3 is needed by mod_geoip-1.2.10-1.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: @VinayAhlawat that’s when the fun begins ;) Good luck with it!